# store xml documents into database?

Tags: xml, database

I have an xml file. Now I wants to store the content of xml into a database(any database) as it is. Because I want to process the xml documents into my application the database. Is there any way to do that efficiently? Guide me, thanks in advance.

Comment: This might depend on the particular DBMS you intend on using. For example PostgreSQL has an XML data type.

Answer (score 0):

Consider estoring it as a [BLOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) column in your database.

Depending on the database and the programming language you're using,  you might be able to deal with this in a more or less easy way.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem, providing whichever database you choose supports CLOB (Character Large OBject) datatype.  If you choose a database which supports XML natively that would be even better; recent versions of the common DBMS products do this: Oracle has XMLType, DB2 and SQL Server have XML column, etc.

Loading the contents of a file into a database column is a programmatic task and really depends on which language you write your app in.

Obviously this is a vague answer, but then I'm afraid it matches the lack of specifics in your question.